# SELECTing "first" (as determined by ORDER BY) row FROM near-duplicate rows (as determined by GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT) within SQLite

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

I have a problem which is a bit beyond me (I'm really awfully glad I'm a Beta) involving duplicates (so `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `COUNT`), compounded by keeping the solution within the standard functions that came with SQLite.  I am using the `sqlite3` module from Python.

Example table workers, Columns:

```
* ID: integer, auto-incrementing
* ColA: integer
* ColB: varchar(20)
* UserType: varchar(20)
* LoadMe: Boolean
```

(Yes, SQLite's datatypes are nominal)

My data table, Workers, at start looks like:

```
ID  ColA  ColB  UserType  LoadMe
1   1     a     Alpha     0
2   1     b     Beta      0
3   2     a     Alpha     0
4   2     a     Beta      0
5   2     b     Delta     0
6   2     b     Alpha     0
7   1     a     Delta     0
8   1     b     Epsilon   0 
9   1     c     Gamma     0
10  4     b     Delta     0
11  5     a     Alpha     0
12  5     a     Beta      0
13  5     b     Gamma     0
14  5     a     Alpha     0
```

I would like to enable, for Loading onto trucks at a new factory, all workers who have unique combinations between ColA and ColB.  For those duplicates (twins, triplets, etc., perhaps via Bokanovsky's Process) where unique combinations of ColA and ColB have more than one worker, I would like to select only one from each set of duplicates.  To make the problem harder, I would like to additionally be able to make the selection one from each set of duplicates on the basis of UserType in some form of `ORDER BY`.  I may wish to select the first "duplicate" with a UserType of "Alpha," to work on a frightfully clever problem, or `ORDER BY UserType DESC`, that I may issue an order for black tunics for the lowest of the workers.

You can see that IDs 9, 10, and 13 have unique combinations of ColA and ColB and are most easily identified.  The 1-a, 1-b, 2-a, 2-b, and 5-a combinations, however, have duplicates within them.

My current process, as it stands so far:

0) Everyone comes with a unique ID number.  This is done at birth.

1) `SET` all Workers to LoadMe = 1.

```
UPDATE Workers
SET LoadMe = 1
```

2) Find my duplicates based on their similarity in two columns (GROUP BY ColA, ColB):

```
SELECT Wk1.*
FROM Workers AS Wk1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ColA, ColB
    FROM Workers
    GROUP BY ColA, ColB
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS Wk2
ON Wk1.ColA = Wk2.ColA
AND Wk1.ColB = Wk2.ColB
ORDER BY ColA, ColB
```

3) SET all of my duplicates to LoadMe = 0.

```
UPDATE Workers
SET LoadMe = 0
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT Wk1.ID
    FROM Workers AS Wk1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ColA, ColB
        FROM Workers
        GROUP BY ColA, ColB
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS Wk2
    ON Wk1.ColA = Wk2.ColA
    AND Wk1.ColB = Wk2.ColB
)
```

4) For each set of duplicates in my `GROUP BY`, `ORDER`ed `BY UserType`, `SELECT` only one, the first in the list, to have LoadMe `SET` to 1.

This table would look like:

```
ID  ColA  ColB  UserType  LoadMe
1   1     a     Alpha     1
2   1     b     Beta      1
3   2     a     Alpha     1
4   2     a     Beta      0
5   2     b     Delta     0
6   2     b     Alpha     1
7   1     a     Delta     0
8   1     b     Epsilon   0
9   1     c     Gamma     1
10  4     b     Delta     1
11  5     a     Alpha     1
12  5     a     Beta      0
13  5     b     Gamma     1
14  5     a     Alpha     0
```

`ORDER`ed `BY` ColA, ColB, UserType, then ID, and broken out by the `GROUP BY` columns, (and finally spaced for clarity) that same data might look like:

```
ID  ColA  ColB  UserType  LoadMe
1   1     a     Alpha     1
7   1     a     Delta     0

2   1     b     Beta      1
8   1     b     Epsilon   0

9   1     c     Gamma     1

3   2     a     Alpha     1
4   2     a     Beta      0

6   2     b     Alpha     1
5   2     b     Delta     0

10  4     b     Delta     1

11  5     a     Alpha     1
14  5     a     Alpha     0
12  5     a     Beta      0

13  5     b     Gamma     1
```

I am confounded on the last step and feel like an Epsilon-minus semi-moron.  I had previously been pulling the duplicates out of the database into program space and working within Python, but this situation arises not infrequently and I would like to more permanently solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I like to break a problem like this up a bit. The first step is to identify the unique ColA,ColB pairs:

```sql
SELECT ColA,ColB FROM Workers GROUP BY ColA,ColB
```

Now for each of these pairs you want to find the highest priority record. A join won't work because you'll end up with multiple records for each unique pair but a subquery will work:

```sql
SELECT ColA,ColB,
    (SELECT id FROM Workers w1 
    WHERE w1.ColA=w2.ColA AND w1.ColB=w2.ColB 
    ORDER BY UserType LIMIT 1) AS id
FROM Workers w2 GROUP BY ColA,ColB;
```

You can change the `ORDER BY` clause in the subquery to control the priority. `LIMIT 1` ensures that there is only one record for each subquery (otherwise sqlite will return the last record that matches the `WHERE` clause, although I'm not sure that that's guaranteed).

The result of this query is a list of records to be loaded with `ColA, ColB, id`. I would probably work directly from that and get rid of `LoadMe` but if you want to keep it you could do this:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Workers SET LoadMe=0;
UPDATE Workers SET LoadMe=1
WHERE id IN (SELECT 
    (SELECT id FROM Workers w1 
    WHERE w1.ColA=w2.ColA AND w1.ColB=w2.ColB 
    ORDER BY UserType LIMIT 1) AS id
    FROM Workers w2 GROUP BY ColA,ColB);
COMMIT;
```

That clears the LoadMe flag and then sets it to 1 for each of the records returned by our last query. The transaction guarantees that this all takes place or fails as one step and never leaves your `LoadMe` fields in an inconsistent state.